# Why do I have to specify the type for regular "const" variables but not for "const" variables defined in "for" loops?

Tags: javascript, typescript, types, typescript-typings

Although TypeScript can infer the types of certain values, all TypeScript  `const` variables **require** a type definition:

```
const x: string = "Hello World!";
```

When you remove the type definition:

```
const x = "Hello World!";
```

You get an error that looks something like this:

[image: TypeScript Error]

So naturally, I assumed that the same applied for `const` variables defined in `for` loops.

The problem is when I tried it, I got this error:

> error TS2483: The left-hand side of a 'for...of' statement cannot use a type annotation.
>
> for (const [series_name, series_data]: [string, SeriesObject] of Object.entries(SERIES)) {
>                    ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

Can someone explain why this isn't allowed?

**NOTE:** this question is **only** about `const` variables, **not** `let` variables.

Comment: Wait, you [don't](https://typescript-play.js.org/#code/MYewdgzgLgBAHjAvDARACQKYBsshgdRACcsATAQhQG4g) get an error on `const x = "Hello World!"` in plain TypeScript.  Looks like you're using some strict [tslint rules](https://palantir.github.io/tslint/rules/typedef/) maybe?

Comment: because typescript concept are around Type definition

Comment: You know, I really can't explain why this isn't allowed... the only relevant issue I can find in GitHub is [Microsoft/TypeScript#3500](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/3500), which is primarily about `for...in` loops.  There the reasoning is that you can't constrain keys to just `keyof T`.  But with `for...of` it seems you should be allowed to annotate the array type, even if it's redundant.   Hmm...

Comment: [Relevant commit](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/commit/7cb2a643503698d3da5469b01d1a8fcd67d2125f#diff-23caaac601698ad4445944f78b566a1f)

Comment: I guess the [right place to ask is in that issue](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/3500#issuecomment-494491530)... we'll see if we get any answer there.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I assume you are using TSLint to lint your code.

Typescript doesn't require you to put a type on const variables, but the *typedef* rule of TSLint does. You will be able to compile your code without the type, and the type of the variable will be `Hello World`, as it's declared with `const`. Il will be assignable to `string`.

However, TypeScript doesn't support putting a type in a for loop. Anyway, it would be redundant since we already know the type of the array to be looped through.

If you don't want to be forced to put a type on your variables, just disable the "variable-declaration" option of the *typedef* TSLint rule.